# Apache htpasswd for multiple websites/dirs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm not 100% familiar how htpasswd works, but i'm wondering if it is possible.

I have one server with one IP and multiple domains there. I need to password protect all of those domains but if possible only at one place. I don't want to go around and make htpasswd for each website.

Assuming that i have all websites places under /var/www/{vhost dirs}

Is it possible at all and how and how?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple domain on single IP is possible from virtual host configuration in apache.

```
 E.g I am running few domains on single machine :
   www.internationalworkersday.com
   www.internationallabourday.com
   www.internationlaborday.com
   www.internationalworkersday.org
   www.apnok.com

#Here is virtual host configuration in httpd.conf


# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www.apnok.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ap/
    ServerName www.apnok.com
    ServerAlias apnok.com *.apnok.com
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www.internationalworkersday.com
    DocumentRoot /home/iwd/
    ServerName www.internationalworkersday.com
    ServerAlias internationalworkersday.com
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log_iwd common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   # ServerAdmin www.internationallabourday.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ild/
    ServerName www.internationallabourday.com
    ServerAlias internationallabourday.com
   # ErrorLog logs/error_log
    #CustomLog logs/access_log_ild common
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^internationallabourday\.com [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.internationalworkersday.com
#DirectoryIndex index.php index.php.var
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www.internationallaborday.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ila/
    ServerName www.internationallaborday.com
ServerAlias internationallaborday.com
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www.internationalworkersday.org
    DocumentRoot /home/iwd/
    ServerName www.internationalworkersday.org
    ServerAlias internationalworkersday.org
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log_org common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www.internationallabourday.org
    DocumentRoot /home/ild/
    ServerName www.internationallabourday.org
    ServerAlias internationallabourday.org
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log_org common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it's not what i need :/